# How to use result from MongoDB aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a query that returns exactly what I need, but I can't access the result, not even when I try to put the result into a variable.

Query:

```js
exp = db.exports.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $match: { 
      level: "high", 
      amount: { $gte: 3 } 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $lookup: { 
      from: "projects", 
      localField: "projectId", 
      foreignField: "_id", 
      as: "project" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: { 
      _id: { $arrayElemAt: ["$project.preset.binder", 0] }, 
      exportations: { $sum: 1 } 
    } 
  }, 
  { $match: { _id: { $eq: "generic" } } }
]);
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "generic", "exportations" : 152 }
```

But when I try to use the `exp` variable (like: `exp.exportations`, or just `exp`), it returns nothing.

When I check the typeof exp, it returns an `object`. So I used `printjson(exp)` to see what was returning and it showed me an object like this:

```
{
    "_batch" : [ ],
    "_useReadCommands" : true,
    "_cursorid" : NumberLong(0),
    "_batchSize" : undefined,
    "_maxAwaitTimeMS" : undefined,
    "_txnNumber" : undefined,
    "_ns" : "designbox.exports",
    "_db" : designbox,
    "_collName" : "exports",
    "_cursorHandle" : {

    },
    "isClosed" : function () {
    if (this._useReadCommands) {
        return bsonWoCompare({_: this._cursorid}, {_: NumberLong(0)}) === 0;
    }
    return this._cursor.isClosed();
},
...
```

Is there any way that I can use the result the way I tried to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation returns an iterator. We need to convert the iterator into an array.

**The following code can get us the expected output:**

```
exp = db.exports.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $match: { 
      level: "high", 
      amount: { $gte: 3 } 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $lookup: { 
      from: "projects", 
      localField: "projectId", 
      foreignField: "_id", 
      as: "project" 
    } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: { 
      _id: { $arrayElemAt: ["$project.preset.binder", 0] }, 
      exportations: { $sum: 1 } 
    } 
  }, 
  { $match: { _id: { $eq: "generic" } } }
]).toArray();
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you got exactly what you needed.

Comment: `"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."`


Sorry, =/

Comment: @NathanGarcia  You cannot upvote but can still accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to do it.